# Got an error in view using the simple_calendar gem in rails 3.2.9

Tags: calendar, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i wanted to include the [simple_calendar](https://github.com/excid3/simple_calendar) via gem. The gem is in my gemfile.

I wrote this code into my view:

```
<%= calendar @events do |event| %>
  <div><%= link_to event.title, event %></div>
<% end %>
```

and this code in the model

```
attr_accessible :event_start_time

def start_time
  event_start_time
end
```

Calling the view i got this error message

```
undefined method `sunday?' for Tue, 01 Jan 2013:Date
```

Today its not the 01 Jan it is the 14 Jan ( I'm confused about this error message )

Does anyone gave an solution for my problem?

Thanks a lot,

Piet

Comment: Where is the View being called from? What is @events being passed into the view as?